# check if UITableViewDelegate is equal to self

Tags: swift

How could I get this to compile?

```
assert(self.tableView.delegate == self)
```

where self is a UIViewController containing the tableview

I get

> WjateverViewController.swift:56:44: Binary operator '==' cannot be
>   applied to operands of type 'UITableViewDelegate?' and
>   'WjateverViewController'

you'd think that maybe

assert(myTableView.delegate == self as UITableViewDelegate?)

would work.
But it does not:

> OffersViewController.swift:56:44: Binary operator '==' cannot be
>   applied to two 'UITableViewDelegate?' operands

I could use help with this wonderful new language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The table view controller and the table view delegate are instances
of a *reference type* (class).

Instances of reference types can be compared with the ["identical-to"
operator `===`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538988), which returns `true` if both references point to the
same object instance:

```
assert(self.tableView.delegate === self)
```